# Can't connect to the guest Ubuntu vsftpd server from the host

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vsftpd

I have installed Ubuntu server on VirtualBox and set up vsftpd server there. I can connect there with its guest terminal and it works fine.

Now the thing is that I am trying to connect to the server from the host machine (which is MacOs) with FileZilla but it fails at the very last moment. I've configured port forwarding, but it seems to still fail.

This is the output I got when trying to connect:

```
Status:         Connecting to 127.0.0.1:2111...
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status:         Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status:         Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status:         Logged in
Status:         Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (10,0,2,15,179,11).
Command:    LIST
Error:          Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:          Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by switching from VirtualBox's network adapter NAT mode to the Bridged Adapter.